# altnet parameter into pimd.conf file

Tags: linux, networking, routing, multicast

I need to route a multicast streams in my private network.
I'm using pimd for multicast routing.
The multicast routing did not work until I put `altnet <multicast_source_ip> masklen 24` to the pimd.conf file.
The problem that I do not always know what the `<multicast_source_ip>`.

I still not understand what the altnet directive is doing?
According to the pimd.conf file:

```
# If you want to add "alternative (sub)net" to a physical interface,
# e.g., if you want to make incoming traffic with a non-local source address
# to appear as it is coming from a local subnet, then use the command:
#   phyint <local-addr | ifname> altnet <net-addr> masklen <len>
# XXX: if you use this command, make sure you know what you are doing!!
```

And how can I solve this problem without `<multicast_source_ip>` using?

Answer (score 1):

The altnet directive to phyint specifies an alternative subnet for a given upstream interface.

Say you want to route from iface eth0 to eth1, the subnet on eth0 is 192.168.1.0/24 and eth1 has 10.0.0.0/24. However, even if the multicast source is located on the LAN eth0 is attached to, it operates on the 172.12.0.0/24 subnet. Adding altnet 172.12.0.0/24 to the eth0 phyint configuration makes pimd accept the traffic as locally originating.

I've added the following new paragraph to the man page for the project on GitHub:

> altnet network/len: Alternative host(s)/network(s) to accept as
>           locally attached multicast sources on a given interface. If a phyint
>           is attached to multiple IP subnets, describe each additional subnet
>           with the altnet keyword.

Usually you shouldn't need this option, so I'm a bit curious about your setup. Did you enable IP forwarding in sysctl.conf, or similar?

Comment: yes, IP forwarding is enabled